# Drawing a phase portrait. What is the indisputable way of doing this?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I came by a question here regarding the sketching of phase portrait of a two-equations system, and they were referred to a certain tutorial from [Paul Online Math Notes](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/). The tutorial ordered to use the representing matrix by taking a certain point (x,y) and find their product (in Av direction of course to get a vector) and the point we get is where some vector in (x,y) is headed. (Not necessary to use a matrix on second thought.)

**The point is:** it works really well in the tutorial, but using it for $$\dot x=3x,\qquad \dot y =y,$$ I get that, for instance, $(1,y)$ points in the direction of $(3,y)$ which will point towards $(9,y)$ to $(3^n,y)$ no matter what $y$ and using it entirely ignoring my intuition and WolframAlpha graph plotter, I always end up drawing straight lines which is clearly inconsistent with what the graph formally look like in some areas.

I would really appreciate it if you could tell me what I am possibly doing wrong.

Comment: "(1,y) points in the direction of (3,y) which will point towards (9,y)" To be precise, the direction field at the **point** (1,y) is in the direction of the **vector** (3,y) thus one cannot iterate this as if (3,y) is a point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"I always end up drawing straight lines": Well, this is odd, [see plot below](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=streamplot+3x%2Cy).

[image]

Comment: I know the lines aren't as straight as I expected following this method, but how is it possible for (1,4) to point in the direction of (3,4) when one can see this is not what the graph depicts? What is my misconception? This is what I am asking for.

Comment: "how is it possible for (1,4) to point in the direction of (3,4) when one can see this is not what the graph depicts?" But the arrow at point (1,4) in the plot included in my answer does seem to go in the direction of the vector (3,4), won't you say?

Comment: To me it looks like it points upwards, meaning $y$ coordinate should grow. I guess I didn't get it well.

Comment: Of course it points upward since $y'=y$ implies that $y$ increases when $y>0$.

Comment: Yes, that I know, but I was led to believe that (a,b) pointing in the direction (c,d) is just like the line created by these two points. That's how it is described here: http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/PhasePlane.aspx 
I am sorry for those misunderstandings; I am not native and clearly it impacts and frustrates.

Comment: Yes, in that the first is a point on the line and the second the direction vector. So the line is $(a+c·t,b+d·t)$.